# Devexpress get horizontal position of particular detail view row's scrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have a master view with many rows, each of these rows has a detail view. Therefore each detail view can have its own horizontal scrollbar.

I wish to iterate through each master-row, check if it is expanded (I have done this) but now I wish to grab the horizontal scroll position of the corresponding detail view per expanded row.

How is this achieved?

I thought it would be masterGridView.GetDetailView(i,0).LeftCoord

but this doesnt work because GetDetailView cant return LeftCoord.....

SOLVED: 
GridView gv = (GridView)mainGridView.GetDetailView(i,0);

gv.LeftCoord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems then you were using the WinForms XtraGrid control. You can read more about the [GetDetailView method here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetDetailViewtopic)

You can also ping the [DevExpress support team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question) directly.

Thanks.